# How to calculate number of seconds within union of time intervals in MySQL

Tags: mysql, set, intervals

Consider a table which holds records with `start` and `end` timestamps. Can anyone propose an SQL statement which counts the number of seconds of the union of all of the time intervals (from `start` to `end`) within the table? Just a heads up: time intervals might have overlaps!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451925/merging-intervals-in-one-pass-in-sql

Comment: I should have found that myself and I don't know how did I miss that. Thanks anyway.