# Sum length of overlapping intervals

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got a table in a Redshift database that contains intervals which are grouped and that potentially overlap, like so:

```
| interval_id | l  | u  | group |
| ----------- | -- | -- | ----- |
| 1           | 1  | 10 | A     |
| 2           | 2  | 5  | A     |
| 3           | 5  | 15 | A     |
| 4           | 26 | 30 | B     |
| 5           | 28 | 35 | B     |
| 6           | 30 | 31 | B     |
| 7           | 44 | 45 | B     |
| 8           | 56 | 58 | C     |
```

What I would like to do is to determine the length of the union of the intervals within group. That is, for each interval take `u - l`, sum over all group members and then subtract off the length of the overlaps between the intervals.

Desired result:

```
| group | length |
| ----- | ------ |
| A     | 14     |
| B     | 10     |
| C     | 2      |
```

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451925/merging-intervals-in-one-pass-in-sql), alas it seems that all of the solutions in that thread use features that Redshift doesn't support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not difficult but requires multiple steps.  The key is to define the "islands" within each group and then aggregate over those.  Lots of subquerys, aggregations, and window functions.

```
select groupId, sum(ul)
from (select groupId, (max(u) - min(l) + 1) as ul
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when prev_max_u < l then 1 else 0 end) over (order by l) as grp
            from (select t.*,
                         max(u) over (order by l rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_max_u
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      group by groupid, grp
     ) g
group by groupId;
```

The idea is to determine if there is an overlap at the beginning of each record.  For this purpose, it uses a cumulative max function on all preceding records. Then, it determines if there is an overlap by comparing the previous max with the current `l` -- a cumulative sum of overlaps defines a group.

The rest is just aggregation.  And more aggregation.